# profile ASP.NET application CPU usage on production IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, performance, profiling, iis-7.5

I am hosting ASP.NET MVC 3 web application on IIS7.5 web server. After several hours application pool start using all three CPU cores and usage goes to 100%. I would like to know  where is performance bottleneck and where CPU spend most time in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JetBrains makes a good profiling tool called [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).  It enables both performance and memory profiling.  I've only used it a little bit, but I have read some good things about it.

Another option is the [ANTS performance profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) from RedGate.  It is also supposed to be very good.

I think either of these would be a good tool to use in starting to trouble-shoot your performance issue.